# Should I chain observables with flatMap, or nest them?

Tags: typescript, rxjs

I have a function that returns `Observable<Foo>`. This function depends on two other functions, which must be called in sequence (func 2 depends on the output of func 1) and return `Observable<Bar>` and `Observable<Foo>` respectively. I've found that I can write the main function in two ways, with one being more concise and the other being more readable, and I'm not sure which style to stick with for other similar functions.

More concise:

```
createFoo(): Observable<Foo> {
  return this.step1()
    .flatMap((result: Bar) => {
      const processedResult = { ..., result }
      return this.step2(processedResult)
    });
}
```

More readable:

```
createFoo(): Observable<Foo> {
  return this.step1()
    .map((result: Bar) => {
      const processedResult = { ..., result }
      return processedResult;
    })
    .flatMap((processedResult: any) => {
      return this.step2(processedResult);
    })
    .map((result: Foo) => {
      return result;
    });
}
```

The first variant only uses one mapping function and is generally a lot less noisy, but I also find it more difficult to tell at a glance what's actually happening. It also seems like it wouldn't scale well if I had more than two observables that needed to be chained.

The second variant is more noisy, with three times the function calls, but I also find it better at explaining what types are output where and how data is processed over the course of the stream. It also makes it much clearer how flatMap differs from the regular map, which is something I've had some trouble keeping my understanding straight on.

Is there a convention with RxJs that favors one or the other? Or is it personal preference?

Comment: chain them to avoid code looking like callback hell (http://callbackhell.com/)

Comment: Refactor when needed. There's no absolute answer. I think first example is ok too when the chain is no need to be reused.